# Showing a Group $G$ is not Simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, proof-verification

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $pq$, where $p,q$ are distinct prime numbers. Show that $G$ is not simple.

Here is my attempt:

$|G|=pq$. If $G$ is not simple, then it has non-trivial subgroups, i.e., subgroups other than the identity and itself.

Let $H$ be a subgroup of order $p$. By Lagrange's Theorem, $|H| \mid |G| \Rightarrow p \mid pq$. Similarly, let $K$ be a subgroup of order $q$ so that $|K| \mid |G| \Rightarrow q \mid pq$. Hence, $G$ is not simple.

I was hoping somebody could verify my proof and point out any errors. As always, any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Careful: it **must** be "If $\;G\;$ is not simple then it has non-trivial **normal** subgroups..." . This (but not only: you also have a logic error) renders your whole proof wrong.

Comment: Have you already studied Sylow theorems?

Comment: Yes, I have seen the Sylow Theorems already.

Comment: Note that by Cauchy's theorem $G$ must have a subgroup of order $p$.  The trick is showing that the subgroup is normal.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, thanks for linking the two questions. After taking a look at it, they do seem to be very similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

Suppose WLOG that $\;p>q\;$ , then

== How many Sylow $\;p$- subgroups are there in the group?

== If and only if *what* a Sylow subgroup is normal?